# Different regions have the same allocation address

Tags: windows, windows-7, operating-system, virtual-address-space, virtualquery

I examine address space of process in Windows 7. I use `VirtualQueryEx` function, and this is some part of my example, where `handleOfProcess_` is handle of some process:

```
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
bool ok = (VirtualQueryEx(handleOfProcess_, (LPCVOID)0x00020000, &mbi, sizeof(mbi))== sizeof(mbi));
ok = (VirtualQueryEx(handleOfProcess_, (LPCVOID)0x00021000, &mbi, sizeof(mbi))== sizeof(mbi));
```

When I do debug, I see, that the `AllocationBase` of **0x00020000** is **0x00020000**, and the `Allocationbase` of **0x00021000** is **0x00000000**, which is the `allocationBase` of another region.

How can it happen?

Thanks to all.

Comment: What's the value of `State`?

Comment: 0x1000 in first call (MEM_COMMIT), and 0x10000 in second call (MEM_FREE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [`MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366775%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> For free pages, the information in the AllocationBase, AllocationProtect, Protect, and Type members is undefined.

Comment: Thanks, so how can i check whether free block is in a region with some AllocationBase address? Richter don't check in VMMap program whether block is free or not.

Comment: If a block is free, then by definition it isn't in an allocated region, so there's nothing to check.  I don't understand your second sentence at all; who or what is Richter?

Comment: Yes you are right. I already understand what i want, so you don't need to understand my second sentence :) thanks again.